# Update recurring event after a date

Tags: google-calendar-api

my name is Erick and I'm doing an integration with google calendar.

I need to update the information (without changing the date) of a recurring event from a date other than the first, and I need the changes to be applied in the following schedules.

Ex: Recurring scheduling 2020-07-20 through 2020-07-30

**change the summary  from the 23rd onwards**

call PUT

[https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/{{id}}/events/{{event_id}}](https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/%7B%7Bid%7D%7D/events/%7B%7Bevent_id%7D%7D)

```
{
 "summary": "TESTE 123",
  "start": {
    "dateTime": "2020-07-23T19:00:00",
    "timeZone": "America/Sao_Paulo"
   },
 "end": {
    "dateTime": "2020-07-23T20:00:00",
    "timeZone": "America/Sao_Paulo"
 }, "recurrence":[
 "RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;UNTIL=20200730T235959Z;BYDAY=MO,TU,WE,TH,FR,SA"
```

]
}

**The problem is that when doing it, the days 20, 21 and 22 are excluded,**

When there is a change of dates I call the PUT and then the POST to create the other schedules, however, in this case there is no change of date and I cannot miss the recurrence.

I really need some help on this issue, this one, thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Google Calendar API - Update recurring events after a date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63003150/google-calendar-api-update-recurring-events-after-a-date)

Comment: Yes, as I couldn't find the functionality to edit the title, I created another one.