# Google Calendar API - Update recurring events after a date

Tags: google-calendar-api

I'm doing an integration with google calendar.

I need to update the information (without changing the date) of a recurring event from a date other than the first, and I need the changes to be applied in the following schedules.

Ex: Recurring scheduling 2020-07-20 through 2020-07-30

change the summary from the 23rd onwards

call PUT

[https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/{{id}}/events/{{event_id}}](https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/%7B%7Bid%7D%7D/events/%7B%7Bevent_id%7D%7D)

`{ "summary": "TESTE 123", "start": { "dateTime": "2020-07-23T19:00:00", "timeZone": "America/Sao_Paulo" }, "end": { "dateTime": "2020-07-23T20:00:00", "timeZone": "America/Sao_Paulo" }, "recurrence":[ "RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;UNTIL=20200730T235959Z;BYDAY=MO,TU,WE,TH,FR,SA"`

The problem is that when doing it, the days 20, 21 and 22 are excluded,

When there is a change of dates I call the PUT and then the POST to create the other schedules, however, in this case there is no change of date and I cannot miss the recurrence.

Answer (score 0):

The way i do it is the one suggested in API docs for `google-calendar-api`

- First edit the original recurring event, limiting it to the date until which  you want no
  change.  Do this by setting the `UNTIL` component of the `RRULE` to point before the start time of the first target instance
- Then create a `new recurring event` with changed info.

You can get a better idea from this doc: [Modify Recurring Event Partially](https://developers.google.com/calendar/recurringevents#modifying_all_following_instances)

Comment: First of all thank you for helping me.

However, this way he loses the link of recurring schedules, I do it when there is a change in the date.

In this case, there is no date change, and I would like to change only one property, such as the summary, without losing the recurrence link